# How to create a variable with text file (Python 3.6)

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, text

I want to create a variable for a text file. How can I do this?

For example:

```
with open("somefile.txt")as f:
    defaVar = f
```

I want to use it to save my settings in my program like:

```
password = input("some word...,hint:%d", f)
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Use `f.read()` to read file content into string.

Comment: It's okay, but try to focus on being clearer than on the grammar.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if `somefile.txt` contains multiple lines:

```
abc
def
ghi
```

You should do this:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as ff:  
    lines=ff.read().split('\n')
print(lines)
```

Output should be:

```
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

But if your file only contain one line:

```
abc def ghi
```

You can use this instead:

```
with open('somefile.txt') as ff:  
    lines=ff.read()
print(lines)
```

Output:

```
abc def ghi
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you just want to print the hint text from a file, use this code for that-

```
   with open("somefile.txt")as f:
        defaVar = f.read()
   password = input("blablabla...,hint: "+defaVar)
```